# Choosing size of frustum based on objects

Tags: opengl-es2, frustum

I would like to show camera frames using OpenGL and rotate the frame in 3D. The frame is placed at (0,0,-frameDepth), and will rotate about the origin.

**Should I decide the size of frustum based on the frame size, or decide the frame size based on frustum?** I would like the frame to cover as much of the screen as possible (maintaining camera aspect ratio), and rotate about the center to say `maxPitch`, `maxRoll` amount.

Specifically which of the following make more sense?

```
    /* (frameWidth, frameHeight) is calculated based on */
    screenWidth = displaySurface.getWidth();
    screenHeight = displaySurface.getHeight();
    float screenAspect = screenWidth / screenHeight;

    float l = -screenAspect, r = screenAspect, t = 1.0f, b = -1.0f, near = 1.0f, far = 10;
    frameDepthZ = 5f;

    Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, l, r, b, t, near, far);    

    frameWidth = (r - l) * frameDepthZ / near; // fill the width of screen
    frameHeight = frameWidth / inputCamera.getCameraAspect(); // assign height based on above width and camera aspect
```

Or,

```
    /* frustum parameters are calculated based on (frameWidth, frameHeight)*/
    screenWidth = displaySurface.getWidth();
    screenHeight = displaySurface.getHeight();
    float screenAspect = screenWidth / screenHeight;

    frameWidth = inputCamera.getWidth();
    frameHeight = inputCamera.getHeight();

    float l = -frameWidth/2, r = frameWidth/2, t = r / screenAspect, b = l / screenAspect, near = 1.0f, far = 10;
    /*the above values don't work, and I can't figure out how to get my frame to fit to the screen. But hypothetically, if these were right, is this the right way to go about it?*/
    frameDepthZ = 5f;

    Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, l, r, b, t, near, far);
```

[Image of Camera frame rendered to screen using method 1](https://preview.ibb.co/cDnazb/Screenshot_20171205_075531.png)

Comment: From your descriptions I am not even sure what you are attempting to do / receive as a result. If your code is working, would you mind providing either a gif of each algorithm running, OR [self-contained executable example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I've added an image, and rephrased parts of the question. Hope this helps you understand what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: oh you are talking about rendering frames from a physical camera real time and rotate them?

Comment: Yes, but that shouldn't affect the answer. My question is straightforward; I have one 3D sprite. Should I set the size of the sprite based on frustum, or the size of the frustum based on the sprite. I'd like the sprite to cover the screen as far as possible, maintaining aspect ratio.